# How should we manage datetime fields in SQLModel in python?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

Let's say I want to create an API with a `Hero` SQLModel, below are minimum viable codes illustrating this:

```
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, SQLModel
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, TIMESTAMP, text

class HeroBase(SQLModel): # essential fields
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, index=True)
    created_datetime: datetime = Field(sa_column=Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
                        nullable=False, server_default=text("now()")))
    updated_datetime: datetime = Field(sa_column=Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
                        nullable=False, server_onupdate=text("now()")))

    team_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="team.id")


class Hero(HeroBase, table=True): # essential fields + uniq identifier + relationships
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    team: Optional["Team"] = Relationship(back_populates="heroes")


class HeroRead(HeroBase): # uniq identifier
    id: int


class HeroCreate(HeroBase): # same and Base
    pass


class HeroUpdate(SQLModel): # all essential fields without datetimes
    name: Optional[str] = None
    secret_name: Optional[str] = None
    age: Optional[int] = None
    team_id: Optional[int] = None


class HeroReadWithTeam(HeroRead):
    team: Optional["TeamRead"] = None
```

My question is, how should the `SQLModel` for `HeroUpdate` be like?

1. Does it include the `create_datetime` and `update_datetime` fields?
2. How do I delegate the responsibility of creating these fields to the database instead of using the `app` to do so?

Comment: Your code example is far from minimal as it relates to your question. I would suggest you at least remove all the relationship and foreign key stuff because it is irrelevant here. That way there is less distraction from the actual issue for future readers of this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Does [the `HeroUpdate` model] include the `create_datetime` and `update_datetime` fields?

Well, you tell me! Should the API endpoint for updating an entry in the `hero` table be able to change the value in the `create_datetime` and `update_datetime` columns? I would say, obviously not.

Fields like that serve as metadata about entries in the DB and are typically **only** ever written to **by the DB**. It is strange enough that you include them in the model for *creating* new entries in the table. Why would you let the API set the value of when an entry in the DB was created/updated?

One could even argue that those fields should not be visible to "the outside" at all. But I suppose you could include them in `HeroRead` for example, if you wanted to present that metadata to the consumers of the API.

---

> 2. How do I delegate the responsibility of creating [the `create_datetime` and `update_datetime`] fields to the database instead of using the app to do so?

You already *have* delegated it. You (correctly) defined a [`server_default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default) and [`server_onupdate`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_onupdate) values for the `Column` instances that represent those fields. That means the DBMS will set their values accordingly, unless they are passed explicitly in a SQL statement.

---

What I would suggest is the following re-arrangement of your models:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import Column, Field, SQLModel, TIMESTAMP, text


class HeroBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, index=True)


class Hero(HeroBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    created_datetime: Optional[datetime] = Field(sa_column=Column(
        TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
        nullable=False,
        server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
    ))
    updated_datetime: Optional[datetime] = Field(sa_column=Column(
        TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
        nullable=False,
        server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
        server_onupdate=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
    ))


class HeroRead(HeroBase):
    id: int


class HeroCreate(HeroBase):
    pass


class HeroUpdate(SQLModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    secret_name: Optional[str] = None
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

(I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to test with SQLite.)

Demo:

```py
from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine, select

# Initialize database & session:
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///", echo=True)
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(engine)

# Create:
hero_create = HeroCreate(name="foo", secret_name="bar")
session.add(Hero.from_orm(hero_create))
session.commit()

# Query (SELECT):
statement = select(Hero).filter(Hero.name == "foo")
hero = session.execute(statement).scalar()

# Read (Response):
hero_read = HeroRead.from_orm(hero)
print(hero_read.json(indent=4))

# Update (comprehensive as in the docs, although we change only one field):
hero_update = HeroUpdate(secret_name="baz")
hero_update_data = hero_update.dict(exclude_unset=True)
for key, value in hero_update_data.items():
    setattr(hero, key, value)
session.add(hero)
session.commit()

# Read again:
hero_read = HeroRead.from_orm(hero)
print(hero_read.json(indent=4))
```

Here is what the `CREATE` statement looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE hero (
    created_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    updated_datetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    secret_name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    age INTEGER, 
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Here is the output of the the two `HeroRead` instances:

```json
{
    "name": "foo",
    "secret_name": "bar",
    "age": null,
    "id": 1
}
```

```json
{
    "name": "foo",
    "secret_name": "baz",
    "age": null,
    "id": 1
}
```

I did not include the timestamp columns in the read model, but SQLite does not honor `ON UPDATE` anyway.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your great response! Can I ask why did you place the `Hero` class above `HeroUpdate` and `HeroRead`? And why is `created_datetime` annotated as `Optional[datetime]` instead of merely `datetime`?

Comment: The order between those classes you mentioned  is arbitrary. The field should be marked as `Optional` for the same reason as the primary key `id` is. In terms of the DB table it of course is not. But from the point of view of the Pydantic model it is optional because you should be able to initialize an instance of `Hero` **without** providing a value for those fields since they will be provided by the DB. [Here](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/automatic-id-none-refresh/) is the relevant docs section.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Daniil Fajnberg's excellent answer two changes I made when I had similar problem.

In `created_datetime` when providing value for `server_onupdate` argument in `Column` you should pass `FetchedValue()` which represents value generated by database server and indicates to SQLModel that this value needs to be fetched from the database after update operation. Of course provided that you have a proper trigger on database side.

Both in `created_datetime` and `updated_datetime` fields you should pass argument `default=None`. Without it when converting HeroRead to Hero you will get validation error. I believe this change was made with Pydantic v2 where `from_orm` was replaced with `model_validation`.

```py
from sqlmodel import FetchedValue

class Hero(HeroBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    created_datetime: Optional[datetime] = Field(
        default=None,
        sa_column=Column(
            TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
            nullable=False,
            server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
        ))
    updated_datetime: Optional[datetime] = Field(
        default=None,
        sa_column=Column(
            TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
            nullable=False,
            server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
            server_onupdate=FetchedValue(),
        ))
```